# Vlookup or Index Match for finding data in a certain date range

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I am currently working on a spreadsheet where I need to find corresponding information to a item number if it falls within a certain date.  However I am unsure how to tackle this.

I'm new to the website and not sure how to paste my example so I will try to explain.

I have four different locations in which I need to find their oil and water production numbers (which are inputed into a table on a separate tab).   I want to be able to lookup this data from the table if they fall within a certain date range.  All the data in the "Production Numbers" sheet have dates associated with them.

Thanks.  Very vague but please let me know if you need any other information.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What does your data look like?

Comment: How many date ranges do you have? If you only have a few you can do a nested if statement. If you have a lot you should look into another solution. Something like this might work =IF(AND(A1>DATEVALUE("04/01/2017"),A1<DATEVALUE("04/30/2017"),VLOOKUP(...),IF(AND(A1>DATEVALUE("05‌​/01/2017"),A1<DATEVALUE("05/31/20‌​17"),VLOOKUP(...),"OU‌​T OF RANGE"))) etc. It can get out of hand quick if you have a lot of ranges though

Comment: Every month of the year will have updated production numbers for that month.  I would like to be able to Vlookup or Index Match the numbers based of the monthly date ranges.

Comment: "please let me know if you need any other information." we need a sample data.. if you don't mind.